# Open source apps with correct code for rewriting to improve Android knowledge

Tags: android

Who can share links on apps, that are open source and have good programming style
to rewrite them for improving /better understanding Android.
I know that there are a lot of open source apps but which of them have good correct code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Sample apps](http://code.google.com/p/apps-for-android/) created by the developers of the Android framework. [This](http://sudarmuthu.com/blog/10-open-source-android-apps-which-every-android-developer-must-look-into) might help too.

http://developer.android.com/resources/browser.html?tag=sample

Comment: Thanks for reply.
I already saw this link.
I want to find the app like Twitter for Android, but wich is open source.
I know that there are:
- android sdk sample
- google android apps
- google android libs
-etc

Comment: Did you mean the source code for a microblogging app for Android?

Comment: No,
I want to find any app with such good design like in Twitter for Android.

Comment: http://android.cyrilmottier.com/?p=240 -GreenDroid(good open-source library)
I want something else.